# Python For Loop and Store Output of Column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to loop through and store each columns cramer_v stat for categorical columns... The df only stores the last one.

```
for col in df2[columns_to_use].select_dtypes(include='category').columns[0:2]:
    print(col)
    cat_summary = pd.DataFrame({  'column_name': col
                                    ,'dtypes':  df2[col].dtypes
                                     ,'target_corr': cramerv_corrected(df2[col], df2[target].astype('category'))
                                      })
```

Answer (score 0):

updated the solution

'cat_summary' is reassigned in each iteration of the loop. Perhaps, try
cat_summary[col].

Question need minimum reproducible example to reproduce and and validate the solution. However, this is what should help, based on details available

Create an empty dataframe, df3,  then concat the dataframe you're creating within the loop. if you have a key (index), you need to introduce that in the concat to have a right join

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()

for col in df2[columns_to_use].select_dtypes(include='category').columns[0:2]:
    print(col)
    cat_summary = pd.DataFrame({  'column_name': col
                                    ,'dtypes':  df2[col].dtypes
                                     ,'target_corr': cramerv_corrected(df2[col], df2[target].astype('category'))
                                      })

    df3 = pd.concat([df3, cat_summary], axis=1)
```

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: Can you post some more details in reproducing the scenarios?

Comment: I am trying to pass each [col] and the cramer_v to a df.

Comment: @Tinkinc  just posted a possible solution, try it. there aren't enough details to reproduce it. This article describes what is meant by minimal reproducible example  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks. It doesnt work. Basic question is how to fill a new df with a loop info from another

Comment: @Tinkinc, made an update in the solution. hope it helps